# Calculating the size of an email in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Say I have an email class that has the following properties:

```
public string From { get; set; }
public string To { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string Body { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, byte[]> Attachments { get; set; }
```

I need to calculate the size of the email and if it is less than 10MB email it otherwise send the content as a fax (to prevent it being bounced from its destination).

I can calculate the size of attachments relatively easily.

Is there an accurate way to calculate the entire email size? I'm guessing I'll need to add the size of the strings as well as any header information that will be appended?

Comment: I think that compared to attachments and maybe body content, all other sizes like header etc. should be rather negligible.

Comment: That is true, but I need to be accurate! ie 1 byte under should be emailed, 1 byte over should be faxed. I can't ignore the size of the strings

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot accurate know the size of the header. Since all servers that pass the mail to the next server might add some data to the header. This can range from one simple line, to the complete score of the spam scanning.

So you will always get it wrong a few bytes.

As for the size of the attachments: They are encoded, so the nr of bytes is not the actual size taken. If you convert them to Base64 and take the length of that string, that's about the size they will take in the email (without attachment header, depending on the attachment name). An estimate is nr of bytes * 1.33.

You can get a good clue, if the mail approaches 10 MB, but when the final and received mail is exactly 10 MB is not known.

Comment: +1 ... and you can't even be sure if your destination assumes 10 MB = 10240 Kb or 10 MB = 10000 Kb.

Comment: In this case I can because it's an internal destination, but point taken

Answer (score 1):

The total size will be the length of the strings plus size of the attachments.

If you're serializing this into a proper email format using a stream, you can use the `Stream.Length` property to get the length easily.

Instead of using `byte[]` to store the attachments in memory, I suggest you use `FileInfo` to get the length of the attachments and then use a `FileStream` to directly pipe the attachment data into a target email file or network stream:

```
using System.IO;
...
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\path\to\file");
long fileSize = fi.Length;
...
// assuming List<string> for attachment file names
foreach (string attachFile in attachments)
{
    using (FileStream afs = new FileStream(attachFile))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!afs.EndOfstream)
        {
            int br = afs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            // assume targetStream is the NetworkStream or FileStream that you want to write to
            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, br);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Attachments are never sent as-is, but rather base64 encoded. This will increase the size of each attachment, e.g `Stream.Length` by a third.

Comment: The mail is a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage and is going to be sent using System.Net.SmtpClient

Comment: In which case, you still don't want to be using byte arrays. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx

Comment: @Polynomial The byte[]'s are converted to MemoryStream and then System.Net.Mail.Attachment before sending.

Comment: I would not worry about 10MB in modern computers. Most clients have 4GB and servers even more.

Comment: @GvS Its always sent to the same mail address and I know that the email limit is 10MB

Comment: It's your decision how close you want the margin. If you know your infrastructure really well, you can make decisions like: in may you make your attachments slightly larger compared to september, because the header added in may is a few bytes shorter (may is only 3 characters).