# Get the MimeMessage size using MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

My SMTP server restricts the amount of data that can be sent per smtpclient session as well as some other constraints.  For example, I want to send 10 messages but the server may impose a limit of 10Mb total.  I would like to calculate the size of the messages so that I know when I need to reinitialize the server connection.

I am using the MailKit library for this effort.

I was considering writing the Message.Body, which would include the attachments, to a MemoryStream, but that seems like overkill just to get the size.

If I have an in memory MimeMessage object, is there a method to determine its complete content length prior to sending?

****------UPDATE------****

If there was not a native option this was my proposed method:

```
using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
      {
         await mailMessage.Body.WriteToAsync(memory);
         curMessageLength = Convert.ToBase64String(memory.ToArray()).Length;
       }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7751030/4800344

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks, while that question is related and may be a path I have to go I was hoping there may be something built in to the MailKit library that maybe I was missing.

Comment: Ah- no unfortunately, I didn't find anything in the docs! I'd just calcaulate the attachment size (as base64 mind you) and the body and that should be enough ish - give or take a small buffer for headers etc,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want can be done like this:

```
// Make sure to prepare the message for sending before you call
// SmtpClient.Send/Async() so that you are getting an accurate size.
mailMessage.Prepare (EncodingConstraint.SevenBit);

using (var stream = new MimeKit.IO.MeasuringStream ())
{
    await mailMessage.WriteToAsync (stream);
    curMessageLength = stream.Length;
}
```

MimeKit has a convenient MeasuringStream so that you don't need to allocate memory.

I'm pretty sure you also want to measure the entire message content (including the message headers).

I don't understand why you were base64 encoding the output message, but I doubt you need or want to do that.

Comment: Thanks again.  RE: the base64, there was a comment  here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7751030/116208) that implied it gave a more accurate length.

Comment: That was talking about the size of an attachment, not the message. The attachments are already encoded in the message.